# How to produce bold italic text in plain TeX

Tags: bold, plain-tex, italic

If I try `{\bf\it text}`, it will be only italic, i.e., the `\it` overrides the `\bf`.

Similarly, it'll be only bold if I try `{\it\bf text}`

How do I get text that is both bold and italic?

I looked for a solution here, but only found solutions for LaTeX (using `\textit{}`) and that doesn't work with TeX.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: @Bobyandbob a mwe would be `x\bye` would that really help in this case, especially as you asked for it after an answer had been posted?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes i prefer to see always a very small mwe, so that everyone could test it (very fast). Sorry didn't see your answer.  I remain convinced that this is useful.

Comment: My typing is rubbish but even I can type `x\bye` faster than I could cut and paste it from this website. I agree that most questions are improved by a MWE but just adding stock comments to every question doesn't really help make the site seem welcoming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\font\zz=cmbxti10

\zz like this?

\bye
```